# Protecting contents of an iframe

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, asp.net-identity

I have two separate Asp.net MVC applications hosted on different servers, but both on the same internal network.

A user on application 1 authenticates and uses app.
One of the pages on application 1 has an iframe in the html, that hosts a page in application 2 passing in a value e.g employee=123.
Application 2 takes employee # 123 and renders some result

```
<iframe src="http://10.0.0.11:8080/GetContact?employee=123" style="width:100%;height:800px"> </iframe>
```

Application 2 has no authentication, but up till now it was only intranet based

Issue now is that times have changed, and users now want this servers accessible over the internet. No VPN. Suddenly application 2 is a risk. Should someone discover the path they could easily look up employee 123, or loop through all possible numbers stealing all sorts of data.

Adding a username/password to the iFrame src url as parameters also won't suffice for obvious reasons.

I was thinking along the lines of application 1 generating a time based key that only application 2 can decode, and only for a period of time.

Is there a better way of securing the content of an iFrame?

EDIT: outer site secured with asp.net identity framework

Comment: How is the outer site secured?

Comment: asp.net Identity framework

Comment: And so you have full control of the site code within the iframe? You can set it up to use the same identity control  so the browser eg sends the same cookies it sends to maintain login on the outer site, to the inner server?

Comment: I have full code control of both systems